# Laravel relationship count

Tags: php, laravel

I know title seems a little complicated, but what I want is simple

- Users (`users`) have comments (`comments`)
- To fetch users' comments, I'm using a `hasMany` relationship
- I'm creating a filter system, so I only want to fetch users who have posted at least 1 comment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `has()`:

```
$users = User::has('comments')->get();
```

Or eager load the `user`s comment models:

```
$users = User::has('comments')->with('comments')->get();
```

**Source:** http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent#querying-relations

Comment: Thanks! Will accept in 5 mins